# Double pipes to do string comparison?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I came across a piece of code in SQL Server which I have never seen before. It looks like this:

```
    select @cnt = 0
    select @strSql = 'update SomeTable set '    
    if @first_name <> '||'
              begin
                select @strSql = @strSql + 'FirstName='''+ @first_name +''''
                select @cnt = @cnt+1
              end
```

My question is, what in the world does `@first_name <> '||'` do? I thought double pipes is used for concatenation but in this case they are comparing the value of first name with double pipes? Can someone shed light into this? I've never seen anything like this. Thanks in advance

Comment: [SWAG](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scientific_wild-ass_guess): It checks for an "empty" pipe-delimited string. There is nothing magic about the operation, it's just a [peculiar name](https://www.kalzumeus.com/2010/06/17/falsehoods-programmers-believe-about-names/). The rest of the code appears to be a dynamic SQL invitation to [Bobby Tables](http://bobby-tables.com/).

Comment: `'||'` is a string literal. `||` is the concatenation operator.

Comment: impossible to tell without the rest of the code... (the part where `$first_name` is assigned a value)

Comment: Adding that double pipes is not a concatenation operator in T-SQL; it is only a literal in this context.

Comment: @jarlh `||` is not a concatenation operator in SQL Server. It is in Oracle and PostgreSQL and something called ["ANSI"](https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/sql-in-a/9780596155322/re92.html).

Comment: @HABO, you're right. I tend to mix up if MS SQL Server supports ANSI SQL double quote delimited identifiers, or if it's the || concatenation. Perhaps I'll remember it now.